# Who was Nina Myers working for?

Tags: plot-explanation, 24

In season 3, Nina Myers is working to acquire the same virus which Jack is trying to acquire. She's working to acquire it for someone else. Is it ever revealed who she was working for?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, this was never revealed.

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/TwentyFour) have it listed as one of their *headscratchers* (i.e. problems without an answer). There's a great discussion on that link about who the client *could* have been, but it appears that the answer really is unresolved, with no *convincing* argument. The actress, Sarah Clarke, did [state in an interview](http://www.24spoilers.com/2011/11/26/sarah-clarke-nina-myers-interview-24/) that she was exhausted and wanted out of the role, and that the show's creators were appreciate and commandeering of that fact.

That suggests the her role in Day Three was really to be given a *proper send off*, considering she was a big part of the show.

Comment: It definitely is a headscratcher: $240 million isn't something to cough at.

Comment: Yeah, that interview sums up what I've thought for a while now. Nina was just too convenient to throw in as the villain of the season, and if they carried her through season 3 and possibly beyond, it would make people think Jack and CTU are simply bad at their jobs. Better to kill her while she's still a fairly popular character for a bit of shock value than to possibly remove all suspension of disbelief.